# Mysql MATCH AGAINST empty field to give all results

Tags: php, mysql, match-against

I have a simple search form which searchs mysql using MATCH AGAINST, which all works fine; however when you search for a stopword or leave the field blank, it returns NO results.

How do you make it that it returns ALL results instead?

Thanks

Comment: um, its complicated, kind of because leaving the field blank and clicking search should display the latest 10 entries from the table - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to develop some search logic in your application.

The `MATCH(columns) AGAINST 'string'` syntax does what it does, which is full-text search.

If your user doesn't give you a usable string, or if the string is obviously a stopword, or if your `MATCH...AGAINST` search result set comes up empty, then you need to do another query that returns the most recent ten entries. But that query doesn't need to do full text matching.

Keep in mind that stopwords are a pain in the neck. For example, there's a rock 'n roll band called "The The."  You probably aren't going to find this band with full-text search.

Comment: ok. thanks. i thought as much but just wanted to check that you couldnt use match against '*' or '?' or something like that which gives all results. thanks again